# Better JLabel movement with KeyListeners

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, keylistener

I'm having a slight problem with the movement of a JLabel using KeyListeners. When I click a key to move my label, it moves a little, pauses for a second, then moves. How can I make my movement more smooth?

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'w'){
            moveY -= 10;
            label.setLocation(moveX, moveY);
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'a'){
            moveX -= 10;
            label.setLocation(moveX, moveY);
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 's'){
            moveY += 10;
            label.setLocation(moveX, moveY);
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'd'){
            moveX += 10;
            label.setLocation(moveX, moveY);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `JFrame` by default never to react to `KeyEvent` listened by `KeyListener`
2. `JFrame` isn't focusable `JComponent`, you would need to use focusable contianer e,g, `JPanel`, but again wrong decision, because is required to set pernament Focus - `setFocusable(true)`
3. don't to use `KeyListener` for `Swing JComponents`, use hight possible abstraction, use `KeyBindings` (search for code examples here)

Comment: +1, for example [Motion using Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/)